# Xamarin iOS: How to add properities into info.plist source section

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin-studio

In xamarin studio when I want to add exra properities to my ios app i would go to source section of the info.plist file and add whatever I want in there. But in Visual Studio I could not find that. Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can change in the info.plist in Visual Studio is very limited. Unless Xamarin provides better support for editing info.plist in Visual Studio, you're stuck with using Xamarin Studio, XCode or any other editor to edit the info.plist.

A word of warning when using Visual Studio to edit info.plist: If you manually made changes to info.plist, make sure you make a copy of it before changing anything from Visual Studio because it *may* overwrite your changes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I ended up turning back to Xamarin Studio.

Answer (score 2):

The Xamarain plugin to Visual Stuidos does not have and "advanced" tab.  The only solution I have found is to do it manually.  Since it seems you have both xmarin studio as well as the plugin for visual studios, there is a "simple" way to accopmlish your goal.

Do whatever you wan to in an empty xamarin studios project, then open the "info.plist" with the xcode option.  Right click on what you need and click copy.  Email it to yourself.

Right click on the "info.plist" in the visual studios plugin, choose "open with" "XML(Text) editor".  Anywhere within the first "dict"  copy your code.

I was looking for a solution to make dropbox work, and I used the info.plist from [this](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/sdks/ios), I ended up adding the following to my info.plist

```html
 <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
  <array>
    <string>dbapi-2</string>
    <string>dbapi-8-emm</string>
  </array>
  <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
      <array>
        <string>db-APP_KEY</string>
      </array>
    </dict>
  </array>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's just an XML file.

1. Right-click on Info.plist in Solution Explorer, and select Open
   With...
2. In the popup dialog select XML (Text) Editor

The XML markup of the Info.plist file will now be visible and editable.